# is there a way to compute the cluster_std of the dataset generated by make_blobs?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, standard-deviation, data-generation

`make_blobs()` is used for generating isotropic Gaussian blobs for clustering.

the param `cluster_std` is the standard deviation of the clusters.

I generated a dataset:

```
x, y = make_blobs(n_samples=100, centers=6,
                       cluster_std=0.60, random_state=1234)
```

and am trying to compute the standard deviation:

```
np.std(x)
```

outputs

```
5.122249276993561
```

which is far from the initial param `0.60`.

Is there a way to compute the standard deviation correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we don't mention the `axis` value in `np.std()`, then all the data points are combined into a single array and then standard deviation in computed.

From [**Documentation**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.std.html):

> **axis :** None or int or tuple of ints, optional Axis or axes along which
>   the standard deviation is computed. The default is to compute the
>   standard deviation of the flattened array.

Even if we mention the axis, we would not get the desired result

```
np.std(x,axis=0)
array([5.51732287, 4.27190484])
```

The reason being the standard deviation, which we had provided earlier is for each cluster and not for the whole dataset.

From [**Documentation**:](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_blobs.html)

> cluster_std : float or sequence of floats, optional (default=1.0) The
>   standard deviation of the clusters.

Now, if we compute the standard deviation for each cluster:

```
>>> sample_size =  100
>>> x, y = make_blobs(n_samples=sample_size, centers=6,
                       cluster_std=0.60, random_state=1234)
>>> for i in range(6):
>>>     print(np.std(x[y==i], axis=0))

[0.34529312 0.71426966]
[0.50416947 0.62691032]
[0.41684885 0.69941778]
[0.5760022  0.58054362]
[0.59779626 0.52716869]
[0.64628073 0.49280287]
```

Still, the values are not always close to the given value `0.60`.

Now, computes the statistical part! Only if we increase the sample size, we could see the sample standard deviation becomes close to population standard deviation (which is the value, we had specified earlier).

If we set the `sample_size` to `10,000,000`, the results seems pretty close!!

```
[0.600691   0.60049266]
[0.60009299 0.60028479]
[0.60048685 0.60019785]
[0.60000098 0.60000844]
[0.59989123 0.60017014]
[0.60010969 0.59936852]
```

Answer (score 1):

From [`make_blobs()`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7813f7efb/sklearn/datasets/samples_generator.py#L698), you can see that the specification of standard deviation `0.60` has been received as argument in `generator.normal(loc=centers[i], scale=std, size=(n, n_features))`, which is the way sklearn generates data points for each clusters.

You should compute the standard deviation for each feature within each cluster:

```
import numpy as np

for i in set(y):
    print('--> label {}'.format(i))
    for j in range(x.shape[1]):
        print('std for feature {}: {}'.format(j, np.std(x[y==i][:,j])))
```

and you get:

```
--> label 0
std for feature 0: 0.345293121830674
std for feature 1: 0.7142696641502757
--> label 1
std for feature 0: 0.5041694666576663
std for feature 1: 0.6269103210381141
--> label 2
std for feature 0: 0.4168488521809934
std for feature 1: 0.6994177825578384
--> label 3
std for feature 0: 0.5760022004454849
std for feature 1: 0.580543624607708
--> label 4
std for feature 0: 0.5977962642901783
std for feature 1: 0.5271686872743192
--> label 5
std for feature 0: 0.6462807280468825
std for feature 1: 0.4928028738564903
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. and what is the relationship between these standard deviations and original 0.60?

Comment: Original `0.60` has been received as argument in `generator.normal(loc=centers[i], scale=std,
size=(n, n_features))`, which is the way sklearn generates data points for each clusters.